# Jetpack Compose: How can I align the height of the items of the first column in a row depending on the height of the second column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want the items of the first column to stretch their height depending on the total height of the other column in the row.

Now I have it:

[image]

And I want it to be like that:

[image]

Is this possible without hardcoding the height through calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compose arrangement 'equal weight' according to this documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement)

```
Modifier.weight()
```